# c++ - call member function on dereferenced object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, object

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
    private:
    T data;
    Node<T> * next;
    public:

    Node(T _data, Node<T> * _next): data(_data), next(_next){}

    T get_data() const {
        return this->data;
    }

    Node<T> * get_next() const {
        return this->next;
    }

    void set_data(T data) {
        this->data = data;
    }

    void set_next(Node<T> * next) {
        this->next = next;
    }   
};
```

now I try to invoke the 'set_next()' function on the dereferenced object pointer:

```
Node<T> new_element(element, NULL);
Node<T> * tmp = this->get_last(); // returns a pointer to the last element
*tmp.set_next(&new_element);
```

when I try to compile the console prints this errer message:

```
error: request for member ‘set_next’ in ‘tmp’, which is of pointer 
type ‘Node<int>*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
*tmp.set_next(&new_element);
```

I don't understand why the compiler wants me to use '->' because '.' is a perfectly fine way to invoke a public member function, right?

However when I put:

```
Node<T> new_element(element, NULL);
Node<T> * tmp = this->get_last();
*tmp->set_next(&new_element);
```

I get this:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
*tmp->set_next(&new_element);
```

I don't understand what that means, can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to operator precedence,

```
*tmp.set_next(&new_element);
```

is the same as

```
*(tmp.set_next(&new_element));
```

which is clearly not what you want.

You may use

```
(*tmp).set_next(&new_element);
```

or

```
tmp->set_next(&new_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp->set_next(&new_element);
```

is the correct usage.

The error message occurs because the `*` tries to dereference the return value, which is `void`.

Comment: to when you invoke a function on a pointer to an object, you use -> and it automatically dereferences the pointer?

Comment: The `->` dereferences the pointer and accesses the member, `()` calls the method.